# Optimize multiple requirejs config file

Tags: node.js, requirejs, r.js, requirejs-optimizer

I have a problem with optimization with r.js

I have a project that have multiple requirejs config file

```
+ app
    - module1    
        * main.js
        * foo.js
        * bar.js
    - main.js
+ build.js
```

that each main.js has self packages

main.js code is:

```
requirejs.config({
    'baseUrl': '../app/',
    'paths': {
        'module1' : 'module1/main'
    }
});
define(['module1'],function(){});
```

module1/main.js code like:

```
requirejs.config({
    'paths': {
        'foo' : 'module1/foo',
        'bar' : 'module1/bar'
    }
});
define(['foo','bar'],function(){});
```

and build.js file is like:

```
({
    mainConfigFile: 'app/main.js',
    baseUrl: 'app',
    name: 'main',
    out: 'dist/main.js',
})
```

when I execute `$ r.js -o build.js` it return an error

```
Tracing dependencies for: main
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Project\Test\app\foo.js'
In module tree:
    main
      module1

Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Project\Test\app\foo.js'
In module tree:
    main
      module1

    at Error (native)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, **`r.js` is simply not able to process multiple `requirejs.config` calls when it builds a bundle.** I've never seen any documentation or issue report, or working example that contradicts this. (RequireJS will let you call `requirejs.config` multiple times, and combine the configurations passed *at run time* but this is not the same as having `r.js` process multiple calls to `requirejs.config`.

You'll have to combine all your calls to `requirejs.config` into a single call that you point `r.js` to with `mainConfigFile`.

I've recreated your setup on my machine and got the same error you did. If I modify the config in `app/main.js` to the following, then I can build the bundle:

```
requirejs.config({
    'baseUrl': '../app/',
    'paths': {
        'module1' : 'module1/main',
        'foo' : 'module1/foo',
        'bar' : 'module1/bar'
    }
});
```

Just for kicks, I've also tried the following **which does not work**:

```
requirejs.config({
    'baseUrl': '../app/',
    'paths': {
        'module1' : 'module1/main'
    }
});
requirejs.config({
    'paths': {
        'foo' : 'module1/foo',
        'bar' : 'module1/bar'
    }
});
```

(Note also that `baseUrl` in the above could be simplified to `.` rather than `../app/`.)